# Overflow has problems with images

Tags: html, css

I try to end my responsive site. My 'overflow:hidden' change my site to not-responsive. The main image isn't show good. 
However, when I put my code into [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5ssc05uj/), all work. How can I fix to get the image show on mobile browsers? 
This is my site: [www.przedszkole.pwoj.pl](http://przedszkole.pwoj.pl/)

Code:

```css
.sec--hero {
    background-image: url(http://przedszkole.pwoj.pl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/img/bg-orange.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec sec--hero">
            <div class="inner">
             <div class="cpnt cpnt--hero">
              <figure class="cpnt cpnt--hero__image">
                     <img src="http://przedszkole.pwoj.pl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/img/main-image.png" alt="" />
                 </figure>
                 <h2 class="cpnt--hero__title">Witamy na stronie internetowej Rodziców obecnych oraz przyszłych Dzieci żłobkowych i przedszkolnych</h2>
             </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: You tried `img { width: 100%; height auto; }`?

Comment: @NiZa, yeah. I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: I would guess that whatever is causing the problem is some other css you haven't included in your question.

Comment: I think that is css because when I turn off the overflow, the image is show but the section include nav then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sec--content::after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(../img/line-white.png);
    /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    max-width: 100%;
```

Is the background-repeat required in this class ? This might be the cause of the issue though i am not sure if this is the problem we are referring to.

Comment: Yeah! The problem was with background-repeat. Do you know why was it? I want to learn something

Answer (score 1):

Setting width: 100%; will fix the issue.

```
.sec--hero {
    background-image: url(http://przedszkole.pwoj.pl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/img/bg-orange.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what makes you think it's a clearfix issue? How did you diagnose? :) Could you update your answer. Cheers.

Comment: OK, it really works. But the menu is unclickable after that and 2nd section goes upper than 1st.

Comment: It's not a clearfix, sorry. Just setting width: 100% is enough in this case. Edited the answer.